# Pipeline question

Tags: clock, clock-speed

I'm having trouble with this question.

> Assume a 5-stage pipeline and a 200 picosecond clock time.
>
> 1. what is the time required to execute one instruction?
> 2. assuming the pipe is kept full, how many instructions can be executed every minute?
> 3. Consider the following assembly language instructions:
>
>    ```
>    Loop: Inc R1 Goto Loop
>    ```
>
>    Once the CPU enters this loop, how many instructions will it execute per second? Explain your answer.

For 1, I wrote one instruction would require 1000 picoseconds to execute.

For 2, I wrote, assuming the pipeline is kept full, one instruction can be executed every 200 picoseconds, so 1 instruction/200 picoseconds x (6.0 x 10^13 picoseconds/1 minute)=3.0 x 10^11 instructions per minute.

I'm a little hung up on question C. Since the CPU is entering a loop, does that mean the pipeline will be flushed so every instruction will take 1000 picoseconds to complete?

Answer (score 1):

Almost. The branch probably causes a pipeline flush, which means that the next `inc` can't start until the previous one has completed. This means that each iteration of the loop takes 1000 ps. But since the loop contains two instructions, that's a rate of 2×10<sup>9</sup> instructions/second.

Actually, it doesn't matter whether or not the branch instruction causes a flush; incrementing the same register multiple times in a row creates a data dependency that would cause the pipeline to stall on every iteration of the loop anyway.

Comment: If the branch causes a full pipeline flush, that would suggest that total time for the loop would probably be six cycles.  I can't see why repeated increments of the same register without the branch-induced delay would take more than five.  Of course, some processors have result-forwarding logic, and some processors have special hardware to avoid pipeline delays with very short loops by using a special buffer to hold the last two instructions executed.

Comment: @supercat: No, the branch itself does not have any results flowing down the pipe that need to be flushed, so it doesn't (or shouldn't) add an extra clock to the loop.

Comment: As Kaz notes, a key question is when the branch is recognized and processed; I would expect PC-relative branches would either have to wait for the ALU to be available, or else use a separate dedicated ALU.  Having a separate ALU and processing unconditional branches early may be helpful, but I would think conditional branches would be the performance hogs since most loops will have at least one conditional branch and compilers could in many cases replace an unconditional branch with a copy of the code between an unconditional branch target and the next conditional branch.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline doesn't have to flush for the loop instruction if the CPU is able to deduce that the branch is unconditional, and fetch the instructions from the branch target rather than the instruction which follows. (For conditional branches this is also possible thanks to branch prediction.)

However, there is the question: at what stage of the pipeline is the instruction recognizes as an unconditional jump.

I agree with Dave Tweed that there is a read-write hazard due to updating the same register. However, it might not actually lead to a pipeline stall, because it can be resolved with bypassing.

Let's suppose that your homework is based on the ["classic five stage RISC pipeline"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline).

Suppose we just have successive INC R1 instructions. One way to deal with the hazard would be to impose a three cycle stall:

```
             t0   t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7
    INC R1  [IF] [ID] [EX] [ME] [WB]
    INC R1       [IF] .... .... .... [ID] [EX] [ME] [WB]
```

The operand is fetched in the ID stage, so the second INC's ID has to wait until the completion of the first INC's WB. But this can be considerably improved with a bypass, which is able to forward the value of R1 without having to wait for the WB stage:

```
             t0   t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7
    INC R1  [IF] [ID] [EX] [ME] [WB]
                               \  bypass
    INC R1       [IF] [ID] .... [EX] [ME] [WB]
```

The ID stage is allowed to fetch the wrong data, but the bypass fixes it up. Now the compiler or assembly language programmer has to find only one instruction to put between these two to eliminate the stall, which is easier.

Since in the inifinite loop example, we have one instruction, the R1 hazard becomes more or less moot, and the problem revolves around how the branch is handled.

Let's say that the unconditional branch is recognized for what it is in the ID stage. So this means that fetching continues past the branch. Let's denote the following instruction as the pseudo-opcode ??? since we don't know what it is.

```
               t0   t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7
L:  INC R1    [IF] [ID] [EX] [ME] [WB]
    JMP L          [IF] [ID] [EX] [ME] [WB]
    ???                 [IF] ---- ---- ---- <-- scrapped; not happening
L:  INC R1                   [IF] [ID] [EX] [ME] [WB]  <-- fetch continues at target
```

At t2, the JMP is in the decode stage, and ??? starts fetching. The processor realizes that it has decoded an unconditional jump, and so it has to re-fetch from the branch target. This does not mean that a pipeline is flushed, but that a once cycle delay takes place.

On some early MIPS processors, the instruction following a branch was not scrapped; it would be executed anyway. It was up to the compiler (or assembly language programmer) to make use of this branch delay slot. If the compiler was not able to make use of the branch delay slot, it has to put in a NOP instruction. This issue probably doesn't matter to your homework question: you can just assume that the loop is followed by a harmless instruction like NOP.

But in any case, the solution dpends on the details of the processor model you're working with and its strategies for dealing with various situations in the pipeline. Study and understand the rules, and draw "staircase" diagrams to trace the evolution in time.